# passport does not set the cookie

Tags: node.js, express, session, cookies, passport.js

if i open express and react server in localhost, it works well. but if i open express server in aws(http), the cookie is not set.

here is my express index.ts code.

```
const app = express();

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.use(
  session({
    secret: sessionSecret,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    cookie: {
      secure: false,
      sameSite: "none",
    },
  })
);

app.use(cors({ origin: frontendOrigin, credentials: true }));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

app.use("/", router);
app.listen(8000, () => {
  console.log("Server has been started...");
});
```

i tried remove `cookie` options in express-session, `origin: true` and `origin: false` in cors.

and i fetch like this

```
const res = await fetch(`${backend}/api/profile`, {
  credentials: "include",
});
```

why it only works in localhost? ofc i opened aws port 8000.